# Why am I obtaining this strange behavior when a child component try to render values from an object retrieved in the parent component?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, primeng, angular-components

I am working on an Angular application and I have the following problem passing data from a parent component to a sub component using the @Input decorator

I have a parent component named **PatientDetailsComponent**. This is the TypeScript code of this component:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { SelectItem } from 'primeng/api';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { PatientService } from 'src/app/services/patient.service';
import { Patient } from 'src/app/shared/interfaces/patient';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-patient-details',
  templateUrl: './patient-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./patient-details.component.scss']
})
export class PatientDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  patientUID: string;
  private sub: any;

  public patient: Patient;

  public patient$: Observable<Patient>;

  editPatientOption: SelectItem[];
  editPatientSelectedOption: string = "info";
  selectedEditPatientId: string;

  constructor(
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private patientService: PatientService
             ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.patientUID = params['id']; 

      this.editPatientOption = [{label: 'Info', value: 'info'}, {label: 'Edit', value: 'edit'}];

      console.log("RETRIEVED PATIENT UID ENTERING IN PatientDetailsComponent: " + this.patientUID);

      //this.loadPatientDetails();

      
      this.patientService.getPatientByUID(this.patientUID).subscribe(patient => {
        console.log("RETRIEVED PATIENT: ", patient);
        this.patient = patient;
      });
      

      
   });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }

  // Load the current patient details:
  /*
  async loadPatientDetails() {
    this.patient$ = await this.patientService.getPatientByUID(this.patientUID)
    console.log("patient$: ", this.patient$);
    //this.loading = false;
  }
  */

  editPatientOptionOnChange(event, patientId) {
    console.log("editPatientOptionOnChange START, event: ", event);
    console.log("Patient ID: ", patientId);
    this.selectedEditPatientId = patientId;
  }


}
```

As you can see into the **ngOnInit()** method of this parent component I am calling a service method retrieving the patient information from Firestore DB, thi one:

```
  this.patientService.getPatientByUID(this.patientUID).subscribe(patient => {
    console.log("RETRIEVED PATIENT: ", patient);
    this.patient = patient;
  });
```

This method set the **this.patient** field with the retrieved value. This retrieved object have to be passed to the child components.

This is the HTML code of my parent component:

```
<div class="container">  

    <p-selectButton [options]="editPatientOption"
                    [(ngModel)]="editPatientSelectedOption"
                    (onChange)="editPatientOptionOnChange($event, 5)"></p-selectButton>

    
    <!--<div>{{(patient$ | async)?.completeName}}</div>-->


    <div *ngIf="editPatientSelectedOption=='info';then info_content else edit_content">here is ignored</div>

    <ng-template #info_content>
        <app-patient-details-info [patientDetails]="patient"></app-patient-details-info>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #edit_content>
        <app-patient-details-edit [patientDetails]="patient"></app-patient-details-edit>
    </ng-template>

</div>
```

As you can see, based on the choose made by the **p-selectButton** select it will be rendered one of the two child component. For both I pass the **patient** object as **@Input** of the child component.

For example this is the TypeScript code of the first child component:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Patient } from 'src/app/shared/interfaces/patient';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-patient-details-info',
  templateUrl: './patient-details-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./patient-details-info.component.scss']
})
export class PatientDetailsInfoComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {

  @Input()
  patientDetails: any

  patientDetail: Patient;
  disabled = true;

  constructor() { }
  

  ngOnInit(): void {

    console.log("PATIENT DETAILS: ", this.patientDetails);

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log("ngAfterViewInit() START !!!");


  }

}
```

Where I have this line in order to retrieve the object passed by the parent component:

```
@Input()
patientDetails: any
```

Now the HTML code of this child component contains:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
      <p>ID Ordine</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <input id="disabled-input" type="text" pInputText [disabled]="disabled" [(ngModel)]="patientDetails.completeName" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

As you can see I am declaring an **input** tag taking the value form the model object passed by the parent to this child component.

And here I have a problem: in the Chrome console I obtain the following output containing errors like this:

```
core.js:4442 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'completeName' of undefined
    at PatientDetailsInfoComponent_Template (patient-details-info.component.html:17)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:7457)
    at refreshView (core.js:7326)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:8473)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:7132)
    at refreshView (core.js:7376)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:8427)
    at refreshView (core.js:7350)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:8473)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:7132)
```

afer these error it is print the outputp of the console.log() defined into the child component ngOnInit() method that print the retrieved object:

```
{id: "RmGajJcqcKrqGKXKKvu3", firstName: "Andrea", surname: "Nobili", completeName: "Andrea Nobili", birthDate: t, …}
```

and this information are correctly rendered into my page:

[image]

I suspect that the problem is that when the child component is loaded the service method retrieving data from Firstore have not yet retrieved data so at the beginning it try to render this line into the child component:

```
 <input id="disabled-input" type="text" pInputText [disabled]="disabled" [(ngModel)]="patientDetails.completeName" />
```

but **completeName** is initially undefined. Then when the object is fully retrieved from the DB I can access to this value.

What is wrong in my code? What am I missing? How can I fix this wrong behavior avoiding all these errors in my Chrome console?

Comment: try enclose all in a div with `*ngIf="patientDetails"`, to avoid when is null. BTW, I suppose is a typo error, but you should only define an unique patienDetaail, the: `@Input() patientDetail` -remove the other `patientDetail:Patient`-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a timing issue. The child will be loaded before the (asynchronous) http request is completed.

You have a few options to handle this:

1. Surround the code in the child with `*ngIf="patientDetails"`.
2. Extend the `*ngIf` in the parent (where you decide which template to display).
3. Define an inital value that is valid (an empty patient).
4. Use the safe navigation operator `?` when accessing the object properties in the child => `patientDetails?.completeName`.

In any case I'd recommend to define an interface for your model and avoid `: any`. This will give you typechecking and autocompletion (also in html if you have the correct extensions, assuming Visual Studio Code).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the same as you:

> I suspect that the problem is that when the child component is loaded the service method retrieving data from Firstore have not yet retrieved data so at the beginning it try to render this line into the child component:

What could be happening is that the asynchronous task is completed **after** the instantiation of `PatientDetailsInfoComponent`. You could try to use a setter function for the `@Input()` decorator in your children component. With this change, the value of the `patientDetails` variable is updated every lifecycle instead of only once:

```js
private _patientDetails: any;
@Input() set patientDetails(value: any) {
  this._patientDetails = value;
}
get patientDetails(): any {
  return this._patientDetails;
}
```